# How to validate PHP form data with htmlspecialchars()

Tags: php, forms, validation, post

I have data coming from html `<form>`.  That did basic HTML5 validation for users convenience, now I need to do server side check.  I have this so far that came from W3.

Now that I run the vars through the validator, how do I apply that validated data? Or is it already validated and I am over thinking it?  But I would still like to use htmlspecialchars()...

```
<?php

$fname = $lname = $email = $message = "";

if ($_SERVER["REQUEST_METHOD"] == "POST") {
  $fname = test_input($_POST["fname"]);
  $lname = test_input($_POST["lname"]);
  $email = test_input($_POST["email"]);
  $message = test_input($_POST["message"]);
}

function test_input($data) {
  $data = trim($data);
  $data = stripslashes($data);
  $data = htmlspecialchars($data);
  return $data;
}

// email body stuff here

// send email 
mail($EmailTo, $Subject, $Body, "From: <$EmailFrom>");

?>
```

**Or is this better? But not sure how to include htmlspecialchars()**

```
$EmailFrom = Trim(stripslashes($_POST['email']));
$EmailTo = "xxx@xxx.com";
$Subject = "Contact Form";
$fname = Trim(stripslashes($_POST['fname'])); 
$lname = Trim(stripslashes($_POST['lname'])); 
$email = Trim(stripslashes($_POST['email'])); 
$message = Trim(stripslashes($_POST['message'])); 

// email body stuff here

// send email 
mail($EmailTo, $Subject, $Body, "From: <$EmailFrom>");

?>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> I have this so far that came from W3.

I assume you mean W3Schools (not to be confused with the W3C who have the domain w3.org): They are extremely low quality. They are often wrong, and even where they are right they frequently leave important things out of their explanations.

---

> Now that I run the vars through the validator, how do I apply that validated data?

`test_input` returns the data. You then assign it to variables. Just use those variables instead of the original data stored in `$_POST`.

That said … the `test_input` function is **entirely unsuitable for the context and you should not use it**.

---

Any escaping and sanitization must be tailored based on what you do with the data.

In this case…

> ```
> mail($EmailTo, $Subject, $Body, "From: <$EmailFrom>");
> ```

… you are sending a plain text email.

---

> ```
> $data = trim($data);
> ```

You might want to remove extra spaces from the start and end of strings that the user has typed by accident.

This shouldn't be *needed* and doesn't help with security, but it does no harm and can make the results tidier.

> ```
> $data = stripslashes($data);
> ```

This is used to remove escaping. The data you are getting should not be escaped in the first place.

This used to be needed when PHP had a [misguided and unreliable auto-escaping feature](http://php.net/manual/en/security.magicquotes.php) but that was removed from PHP years ago and, even when it was there, code should test to see if the feature is turned on or not.

Since there isn't any escaping to remove, this can remove real data.

Don't do that.

> ```
> $data = htmlspecialchars($data);
> ```

You are sending a plain text email. Not an HTML email. The input isn't going anywhere near HTML.

Escaping it for HTML will just risk making the reader of the email see HTML entities instead of the characters you want them to see.

Don't do that.

Answer (score 0):

Four related issues here: trimming data, escaping characters, data validation, and data sanitization.

Trimming the input is good, because the input may have some unnecessary characters such as space or figures. For example, if the input is `$str = "   1.8 Some input"` and you only want to store `"Some input"` then you could use `$str = ltrim($str, ' .0123456789');` (with a space at the beginning of the second parameter).

It is common to pass posted data through `mysqli_real_escape_string()` which helps create a legal sql statement. This would, among other things, escape quotes and allow them to be entered smoothly into the dataset. For details see: http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.real-escape-string.php.

Using `stripslashes` could remove splashes that were used to escape some characters. For example, if `$name = "O\'reilly";` using `stripslashes($name)` gives the `$name` as `O'reilly` which can disrupt the logic of your sql statement because of the unescaped quote. So then you would not use `stripslashes` after using `mysqli_real_escape_string`.

It is always important to validate data on the server side. But use of `htmlspecialchars()` will not remove anything.  Whatever is encoded with it will be as it was when the data is decoded  with `htmlspecialchars_decode()`, after reading it from the database where it was stored.

**PHP Filters** should be used for both validation and sanitation of data sent to the server side. For example, you could sanitize and check a posted email as follows:

```
// Sample email address, possibly got from $email = $_POST['email']
$email = "someone@@example.com";

// Remove all illegal characters from email
$email = filter_var($email, FILTER_SANITIZE_EMAIL);

 // Validate e-mail address
if(filter_var($email, FILTER_VALIDATE_EMAIL)){
    echo "The <b>$email</b> is a valid email address";
} else{
    echo "The <b>$email</b> is not a valid email address";
}
// gives: The **someone@@example.com** is not a valid email address
```

For a gentle introduction to PHP filters, see for example, https://www.tutorialrepublic.com/php-tutorial/php-filters.php from where I got the above example. For more details see http://php.net/manual/en/book.filter.php.